# Spotify Embed code (iframe) won't work in Markdown

Tags: html, reactjs, markdown, next.js

Using React-Markdown on Next.JS, the post pages are stored as Markdown files, but for some reason the Markdown file won't render the iFrame. However if I use a standard Markdown Editor such as the one I created markdown-edit.now.sh the embed code works perfectly fine.

Any reason as to why it wouldn't be loading on my pages but is fine in

Embed Code

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/0BRICN5TGMT1WqFcZkYOaF" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<ReactMarkdown escapeHtml={false} source={blog.content} />
```

Comment: Warning for everyone passing here: make sure the content you're inserting into ReactMarkdown is safe, as this allows for dangerous HTML tags

Answer (score 0):

ReactMarkdown handles iframes as "dangerous html". To disable this just do:

```
<ReactMarkdown allowDangerousHtml={true}>Your content here<ReactMarkdown/>
```